# Rails / ActiveRecord: how to get all articles whose tags are included in current article tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

This one is a head scratcher!

I'm trying to get all articles whose categories are included in current article's categories.

What I have so far, which is wrong of course:

```
@rq = Article.includes(:tags).where(tags: { name: @article.tags.first.name })
```

There is a join table setup between `Article` and `Tag` (has_and_belongs_to Tag and has_and_belongs_to Article). Essentially I can access all tags of current article with `@article.tags` and all articles of current tag with `@tag.articles`.

Comment: Please show db schema of those two models

Comment: @Fallenhero added more info on the database design. There is a join table setup between them.

Comment: So you have a has_and_belongs_to_many relation?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. Added to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something easy like:

```
@rq = Article.joins(:tags).where(tags: {id: @article.tag_ids})
```

If I understood your requirement correctly.